# terraform plan hangs on github actions with linode lke

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, github-actions, linode

I'm trying to use terraform and Linode's kubernetes cluster (LKE) in Github Actions, but I'm running into an issue when I try to run the `plan` or `apply` commands – they just hang. My guess is that because the `terraform init` generates an output that the `terraform plan` cannot access. But I'm not sure how to make that outcome available to the next step.

My github actions workflow file looks like this:

```
init-terraform:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: 'some-branch'
      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TERRAFORM_API_TOKEN }}
      - name: Terraform Init
        run: terraform init

      - name: Terraform Plan
        run: terraform plan

      - name: Terraform Apply
        run: terraform apply -auto-approve
```

The init seems to work fine, but the plan just hangs. When I run this locally, the plan takes about 20 seconds.

My `main.tf` file in the repo looks like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    linode = {
      source  = "linode/linode"
      version = "=1.16.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "linode" {
}

resource "linode_lke_cluster" "lke_cluster" {
    label       = "my-label"
    k8s_version = "1.21"
    region      = "us-central"

    pool {
        type  = "g6-standard-2"
        count = 3
    }
}
```

I have set the `TERRAFORM_API_TOKEN` as a github secret and I set `LINODE_TOKEN` as a terraform environment variable.

What am I missing that is causing the terraform call to hang?

Answer (score 2):

Although, I'm not familiar with linode's provider, I have a strong hunch that you need to include

```
        with:
          cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TERRAFORM_API_TOKEN }}
```

in each of your steps.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I ended up adding the `LINODE_TOKEN` as an environment variable to each of the steps and that seemed to take!